# Unsure how to troubleshoot

Tags: excel, vba, hide

I have a drop down menu in the first tab of my workbook that calls macros with each selection. The problem is that one of the nested macros (HideTermsAndConditions macro nested in the Main_Budget_Without macro) from the drop down menu is no longer working even though it works by itself and in a different macro selection from the drop down menu. The HideTermsAndConditions macro also used to work in this Main_Budget_Without macro. The workbook is protected but all the other macros don't seem to be having an issue. The worst part is that no error is shown in the VBA editor when I run the Main_Budget_Without macro. While I know it is the HideTermsAndConditions macro that is the problem (since the terms and conditions aren't hidden when the Main_Budget_Without macro is run) I don't know how to fix the problem in this scenario.

I tried running the Main-Budget_Without macro in the VBA editor. Every macro that Main_Budget_Without calls works except the HideTermsAndConditions macro. And yet at the same time, HideTermsAndConditions macro works when run by itself in the VBA editor. Not only that, it works when called in a similar macro selection from the drop down menu.

````
Sub Main_Budget_Without()
Call TurnOffFunctions

Call HideTermsAndConditions
Call MakeManagementFee10
Call HideDiscountColumn
Call HideTotalDiscount
Call ComA_UndoUnitRatesForRolesInServicesTab
Call ComA_UndoDayRates
Call ComA_UnhideRows19And20InSOW
Call ComA_AddDanielleRolestoRolesColumnInServicesTab
Call ComA_UnhideAllRowsBelowThirdPartyTableInSOW

Call TurnOnFunctions
End Sub```
````

The only macro in the nested macro above that isn't working is the first one - HideTermsAndConditions.

````
Call TurnOffFunctions
Sheets("SOW").Range("723:813").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Call TurnOnFunctions
End Sub```
````

Comment: What happens if you step through with F8? What happens when it gets to the HideTermsAndConditions macro? Does it return properly from TurnOnFunctions?

Comment: Hey @teylyn. When I step through it, it jumps to the TurnOffFunctions macro. Not sure why it would do this since just about every macro in this workbooks contains the TurnOffFunctions and TurnOnFunctions and I haven't had a problem with them yet.

Comment: Well, you tell it to jump to the TurnoffFunctions macro, so that does not surprise. When happens when you continue with F8 and it returns to the calling macro?

Comment: I'm on a mac so I'm pressing debug -> step into which I believe is the same thing but wanted to check. It steps through the macro as usual without finding any error which is why I'm having such a hard time fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it made a difference but I tried moving the sub HideTermsAndConditions around in the sequence of called macros in the drop down macro Main_Budget_Without (moved it to the end right before TurnOnFunctions instead of being 2nd after TurnOffFunctions) and for some reason, that fixed it. Not necessary since the drop down macro is now working but would appreciate it if anyone can explain why this happened so I can know if this might happen again in the future.